# Why this python multi-thread approach take more time than single thread to solve the same task?

Tags: python, multithreading, process

Why this python multi-thread approach take more time than single thread to solve the same problem?

Note that my computer is multi-core processor cpu.

I wrote the same code in both ways and make a comparison. Surprisingly single thread way is faster! Anyone have any thoughts?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

L = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]

def gen(index,value):
    if index==len(L):
        return 1
    count=0
    for i in range(len(value)+1):
        count+=gen(index+1,value[:i]+[L[index]]+value[i:])
    return count


#Single thread approach
print gen(1,[1]) #this takes 480ms to run!



#Multi-thread approach
from threading import Thread
def t1_start():
    global pointer1
    pointer1=gen(2,[2,1])

def t2_start():
    global pointer2
    pointer1=gen(2,[1,2])

pointer1=0
pointer2=0
t1=Thread(target=t1_start,args=())
t2=Thread(target=t2_start,args=())
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
#print pointer1+pointer2 #this takes 650ms to run!
```

Comment: are you using CPython?

Comment: please do a bit of research, for example google `python threading core GIL` and read the first few SO QA's

Comment: I did some profiling to see my CPU usage while running. I'm now suspecting maybe Python interpreter/optimizer or Intel CPU instruction set is pretty smart to handle even single thread solution to force it run on multiple CPUs.. dont know if that's the right direction

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem in Java.
The users suggested that the overhead, which the creation of the threads costs, was slowing down so much, that it took longer.
I recommend you to try your threaded code with really really complex calculations and much more numbers in your gen(index, value) function.
The threaded code might be better than the simple solution, if the gen function would take more time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.

I simply increased the task from 10 digit array to 12 digit array, this takes roughly 1 min for my computer (i7 2.3G  16GB) to solve the problem.

so the new result is this:
single thread: 50 sec;
multi-thread: 72 sec.

I also tried implement it using multi-process. surprisingly multi-process cut the time in half.

Comment: nice Tests. I did'nt expect that. Strange. I was sure that multheading will be faster :O Anyways, good luck with Multi process :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362732/why-my-multi-threading-code-spend-more-time-than-single-threading-code?rq=1
Here's your answer on the same question asked by a different user :)